# a2dp sink profile in android

Tags: android, audio

I have a question about a2dp sink profile in Android. I'm connected to other bluetooth device and I'm trying to play something from it but I can't hear sound.
Which place should I write some debugs to see that audio data are received and passed to rest of audio stack? I mean where are callbacks with audio data?
I was checking audio_a2dp_hw hal to it looks like it's not active in this type of connection.

Regards